# Mongodb Document size

Tags: mongodb

A quick question please to be sure.

I have the following example of document in my collection guest

```
"_id" : "JM15061985",
    "last_name" : "Michel",
    "first_name" : "Justine",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "title" : "Mme",
    "telephone" : 3375,
    "mail" : "justine.michel@yahoo.com",
    "language" : "French",
    "birthday" : ISODate("1985-06-14T22:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "VIP",
    "company" : "Test",
    "address" : [
        {
            "street" : "45 Avenue de Paris",
            "city" : "Nice",
            "zip_code" : "06072",
            "country" : "France"
        },
        {
            "street" : "12 square xvy",
            "city" : "Toulon",
            "zip_code" : "83072",
            "country" : "France"
        },
]
```

I know that one document ins Mongodb can't exceed 16Mb.
So my basics questions are :
What does 16Mb represents really? (any exemple maybe?)
In my example, is each address considered as a document or this is only one document?

Comment: In you example, it is not each address but the entire thing is considered as one document and address is just one field of type array. Regarding the 16 MB size refer to [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/limits/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16MB is the maximum size of the [BSON-document](http://bsonspec.org/) that represents your document. This includes nested objects, like your `address` example, and also key names (not just the values).

There's also some overhead per document property, as explained [here](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html).

To check BSON document size for a particular JS object, and if you happen to use Node.js, you can use the [`bson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) module:

```
var BSON = new (require('bson')).BSONPure.BSON();
var bson = BSON.serialize(obj, false, true, false);

console.log('bson size', bson.length);
```

There should be similar solutions for other programming languages.

Comment: You seem to assume that the OP is using Node. Which, in all likelihood, he does not.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko fair enough, I'll edit my answer to reflect that :-)

Comment: Does this function exist for php?

Comment: @Ahmed-F looks like [`bson_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bson-encode.php) is similar.

Comment: Thanks will check that