# Nodejs mongodb fetching document size without actually fetching cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My question is, how can I get a `cursor` size **(in KBs)** without actually fetching it ?

I've already examined a lot of question such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291664/mongodb-document-size) But I don't want to fetch query result to learn how much **KB** is it.

I just want something like:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {

  var collection = db.collection('simple_query');

  // Insert a bunch of documents for the testing
  collection.insertMany([{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}], {w:1}, function(err, result) {
    test.equal(null, err);

    collection.find(/**SOME QUERY*/).size(function(err, SIZE) {
      test.equal(null, err);
      test.equal(32111351, SIZE); // in bytes or kilobytes whatever
      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I wonder if MongoDB even tracks this sort of information internally (assuming that you want to retrieve the size of the results of a query, and not the size of the entire collection).

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method to get the size (in bytes) of a cluster. Can't find anything in the docs anyway. I think you'll have to iterate over returned documents.

Comment: But if there are millions of documents which will return from the find method's execution, I can't do that...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var avgSize = db.collectionName.stats().avgObjSize;

// ...

collection.count(/* some query */, function(err, count) {
    var approximateSize = count*avgSize; // This could work for simple database models
}
```

I know its not perfect, but it is the best way i found.

Comment: I wonder how this helps me to get size of documents without fetching them ??

Comment: i think there is no other way to get the size

Comment: Sorry but now your edited answer returns all collection's storage size, I want a specific cursor's size.

Comment: I already thought that, thank you but if user uses a PROJECTION, it calculates really wrong values