# nodejs - both IF and ELSE execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There has to be a standard way of checking for existence of a document and then inserting if it doesn't exist.  This is something we all do, since the dawn of time.  But the examples out there only show, like, half a routine.  I don't get it.  So I came up with the following code.  And for some reason, both `if` and `else` execute.  The function isn't getting called twice, so... why is it happening?

The output is:

```
Connected correctly to server
got doc
inserted doc
Disconnected from server successfully
```

The code is:

```
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    var cursor = db.collection('mycoll').find(mydoc).limit(1);
    // i need 'each' in order to test if doc exists.
    // will execute once because i said limit 1.
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        if (doc != null) {
            console.log("got doc");
        }
        else {
            mydoc.date_submit = new Date();
            db.collection('mycoll').insertOne(mydoc, function (err, r) {
                assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
                console.log("inserted doc");
                db.close();
                console.log('Disconnected from server successfully');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you should log the size of the cursor

Comment: there is a limit of 1 on the cursor, so I can understand why it isn't checked, but yeah - log the size of the cursor!

Comment: Are you looking for an *upsert* operation…? That updates the document if found else inserts a new one.

Comment: As written, the `if ... else ...` statement will execute only one of the options. And you're specifying limit = 1, so you expect to get exactly one item. You're (correctly) assuming that one of these is incorrect, but you're guessing that the `if ... then ...` is where the error lies. I'd guess it's the opposite, that your query is not returning what you think it is. Why guess that? Because a basic language feature is less likely to give you weird results than a value returned from a library. Check your `cursor`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  To answer your questions - 1) I would use upsert, but I don't because we are adding a timestamp.  upsert would succeed every time.  2) Check my cursor... ok I tried that, but the object looks exactly the same whether a record exists or not.  Someone else asked the same thing - how do i get cursor size - and were just as confused. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657534/nodejs-mongodb-fetching-document-size-without-actually-fetching-cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the `if (doc != null)` you can identify the end of the loop. Thes mean that even if you limit the results to 1, the first iteration will give you back the document that you queried and in the second iteration the cursor will be null and indicating that this should be the end of the loop/results.

The logs are like that:

```
Connected correctly to server
got doc
inserted doc
Disconnected from server successfully
```

because you are executing an asynchronous operation in the else statement.

Cursor is not aware about your limit in the query.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that (cursor not aware of limit).  Thank you.  When you say 'identify the end of the loop', do you mean `break` out of the loop?  Or something else?  (It's telling me `cannot determine target for break`.)  `return` has no effect, either; both `if` and `else` still execute.

Comment: It means that there are no other results to iterate. For example, this query `db.collection('mycoll').find(mydoc).limit(1);` can give back to you no results or one result. In the case of no results you will see the `got doc` in your console. In the case of 1 result you will see the output that you've already posted. I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve but I would suggest using the mongo findOne and then check if the doc var is null insert the doc that you want and completely forget about the cursor iteration.